# iOS Charts - How to initialize LineChartView programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-charts

I want to use iOS charts for my objective-c project. Since the UI is written in code completely, I don't want to create a nib file for the chart view specifically. However, a simple **init** or **initWithFrame** to create the **LineChartView** is giving me **nil**

```
//Declare chartView property in header
@property (nonatomic, weak) LineChartView* chartView;

//Call to init chart     
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), 
CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds));
self.chartView = [[LineChartView alloc] initWithFrame: frame];
```

Here, self.chartView is **nil** after calling above code.

Comment: make the property as strong instead of weak. Also where do you init the property, post the complete code.

Comment: That worked !! Can you explain a little as to why it didn't work with the weak property ? IBOutlets are usually marked as weak.

Comment: `weak` will release it immediately once its created, since there's no other strong object retain it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my exprience you need to remove `Weak` property only `nonatomic` will work while you are assigning object with Init method.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) LineChartView *lineChart;
```

This one should replaced with

```
@property (nonatomic) LineChartView *lineChart;
```

as if you create weak property it will release after its assignment.

also while you make this type of mistake `XCode` throws warning like below :

> warning: assigning retained object to weak property; object will be
>   released after assignment [-Warc-unsafe-retained-assign]
>       self.lineChart = [[LineChartView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
>                      ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 1
>   warning generated.

So in-sort never use `weak` while you are assigning any `retain` object in it.

Hope this will help!